# Atomic timer callback design question

Tags: c#, timer, callback

I want to call the timer callback just one time until it finishes the task. For example if the timer interval is five minutes and the task may be done within 2-20 minutes, if the previous task is not completed, new threads doesn't enter callback method.

Currently I do this by a volatile counter but it doesn't make sense to me. There should be a best practice. Sample code:

```
private volatile int _counter = 0;
private readonly object _syncLock = new object();

void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(syncLock)
    {
        if (_counter > 0)
            return;
        else
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    }

    // Method body

    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `lock` _and_ `Interlocked`

Comment: @Henk: without it, many threads will enter method. The actual interval is a small value.

Comment: I thought it was minutes. But even then you need a Monitor, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is simple enough actually. When you initialize the timer set the `AutoReset` property to false.

```
_timer.AutoReset = false;
```

Then at the end of your event handler invoke this:

```
_timer.Start();
```

Comment: That would be the Timers.Timer, Threading.Timer does not have a AutoReset.

Comment: @Henk - By examining the parameters of the event handler I reasoned that this was in fact a `System.Timers.Timer` instance.